# How to setup Moq to execute some methods of a Moq

Tags: moq

I have a test where I pass in an object like so:

```
var repo = new ActualRepo();

var sut = new Sut(repo);
```

In my test, Repo has one method that I need to actually execute, whilst another method I want to mock out and not execute.

So for example, take this pseudocode:

```
var repo = new Mock<IRepo>();

repo.Setup(m => m.MethodIWantToCall()).WillBeExecuted();
repo.Setup(m => m.MethodIWantToMock()).Returns(false);
```

Using Moq, is this possible and how can it be done?

EDIT:
I've used TypeMock in the past and you can do something like.

```
Isolator.When(() => repo.MethodToIgnore()).WillBeIgnored();
Isolator.When(() => repo.MethodToActuallyRun()).WillBeExecuted();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with Moq if you use the same object unless one of the method is virtual and you are basing your mock on a type rather than an interface.

That's because when you are passing a mock object based on an interface, you aren't passing a real object so it does not have access to the real methods of the object.

You are passing a [dynamic proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) which will respond to methods it has been setup to respond to.

I believe TypeMock rewrites the assemblies at runtime to achieve this, something Moq definitively doesn't do.

If you want to achieve similar results with Moq:

- You could mock both methods
- You would have to extract both methods to different dependencies so as to mock one dependency and not the other.
- You could have the method you need mocked be virtual, which would be the solution I would prefer.

**EDIT** : I edited my answer for correctness after reading [AlanT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12624872/153797).

Comment: I suspected as much, just needed to hear it from someone else :)

Comment: @JasonEvans: This, along with the ability to mock "everything" (not just abstract classes or interfaces) are the two features I frequently see people finding lacking in Moq.

Answer (score 5):

Not too sure from the question if this is useful but it is possible to partially mock an object if the method that you want to mock is *virtual*.

```
public class Foo {
    public string GetLive() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    public virtual string GetMock() {
        return "Hello";
    }
}

public class Snafu {
    private Foo _foo;
    public Snafu(Foo foo) {
      _foo = foo;
    }

    public string GetMessage() {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", _foo.GetLive(), _foo.GetMock());
    }
}


[TestMethod]
public void NotMocked() {
    var snafu = new Snafu(new Foo());
    Assert.AreEqual("Hello Hello", snafu.GetMessage());
}


[TestMethod]
public void Mocked() {

    var mockFoo = new Mock<Foo>();
    mockFoo.Setup(mk => mk.GetMock()).Returns("World");

    var snafu = new Snafu(mockFoo.Object);

    Assert.AreEqual("Hello World", snafu.GetMessage());
}
```

Comment: OK, interesting idea. Let me get some time to look into this, forgot about the virtual method approach.

Comment: It seems like this is a better answer than mine. I didn't know you could do this.